# Emulator getting disconnected on making calls

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to develop an application based on phone calls for which I just started with placing simple logcat messages and as soon as I place a call most of the time the emulator is getting disconnected and it works only if I reset the adb, also I checked this making calls from ddms and between two emulators but the result is same: the emulator gets disconnected and logcat doesnt show that messages.

Is there any solution for this problem? What is the cause for this problem?